# How do I execute 7za list command programmatically and output the results to a file?

Tags: c#, cmd, 7zip

With origional testing in command prompt, I was able to output the results of a 7za list command, with findstr, to a text file and I needed this same behavior in my application.

Executing `7za.exe` directly with other commands like `findstr` or a redirection operator `>>` resulted in `exit code 7`.

How can I execute a 7za command, programmatically (C#), to list contents based off of a findstr command and finally write those results to a text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and testing I was able to run `cmd.exe` and write commands to the process. I also did not have to call `exit`.

```
Process cmdProcess = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

cmdProcess.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
cmdProcess.Start();

String sevenZipListFindStrCommand = "Library\\7za.exe l \"C:\\temp\\testSource\\archive.7z\" -pXYZ | findstr /i VM >> C:\\temp\\output.txt";
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = cmdProcess.StandardInput)
{
    if (streamWriter.BaseStream.CanWrite)
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(sevenZipListFindStrCommand);
    }
}

cmdProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Just a notice: cmd won't run reliably if you are writing a windows service. By calling cmd, the system suppose that you are in the interactive mode. However, the same effect could be done by similar code: just calling "7za.exe" directly (processStartInfo.FileName = ".../7za.exe") & use StreamWriter to write the StandardOutput

Comment: @HoàngLong - Thanks for the advice! I'll have to check it out.